# What is the name of this scroller component?

Tags: navigation, terminology, scrolling, component

[image]

I have these arrows that when clicked scroll n cards to the side.

I would like to find a React component that does that, but I don't know how is it called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen libraries that call this effect a "carousel." Or some type of "carousel slider." There are many open source repositories that offer this for React.

Comment: +1, though I've often seen them called *either* **carousel** *or* **slider**.

Comment: Thanks! I found exactly what I needed : https://github.com/akiran/react-slick